# Pthreads and Mutexes for RaceCondition Control

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm having an issue where my code is not acquiring the required mutex lock in order to manage Race Conditions. The code intentionally causes race conditions by using nanosleep to pause the threads and let them compete for the same data. My issue is that when adding the mutex lock to the code, not all of my threads are executing and thus giving a wrong value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 10

//Global Value
int SHARED_VALUE = 0 ;
pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* add10(void*);
struct timespec ts = {0, 10};


int main() {
    //Required for thread creation
    pthread_t thread_id; //Thread Identifier
    pthread_attr_t attributes; //Default Attributes
    pthread_attr_init(&attributes); //Attributes Initialized to Default            Values

    //Initialize Mutex
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error Creating Mutex\n");
        return -100;
    }
    //Spawn 10 Threads
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS;i++){

        thread_id = i+1;

    if(pthread_create(&thread_id,&attributes,add10,thread_id) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error Creating Thread: %d", thread_id);
            return -100;
    }
 }


for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
    pthread_join (thread_id,NULL);
}

//pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

printf("Shared_Value: %d", SHARED_VALUE);
```

}

```
void* add10(void* arg) {
    int thread_id = (int *) arg;
    if ((pthread_mutex_lock(&lock)) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Lock Acquired:%d\n", (int *) arg);
        //Access Shared Value
        int local_value = SHARED_VALUE;
        fprintf(stderr, "\tInitial Local Value: %d\n", local_value);
        local_value = local_value + 10;
        fprintf(stderr, "\tPost Local Value: %d\n", local_value);
        //Stall thread for race conditions
        nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
        SHARED_VALUE = local_value;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "No Lock!\n");
        pthread_exit;
    }
    if ((pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error on unlock\n");
    }
}
```

Output Looks Like:

```
Lock Acquired:5
    Initial Local Value: 0
    Post Local Value: 10
Lock Acquired:6
    Initial Local Value: 10
    Post Local Value: 20
Lock Acquired:4
    Initial Local Value: 20
    Post Local Value: 30
Lock Acquired:7
    Initial Local Value: 30
    Post Local Value: 40
Lock Acquired:9
    Initial Local Value: 40
    Post Local Value: 50
Lock Acquired:10
    Initial Local Value: 50
    Post Local Value: 60
Shared_Value: 60Lock Acquired:8

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: int main() => return 0;

Comment: Note that, even when you have fixed your 'main() exiting early' issue, as described in the answers, 'nanosleep(&ts, NULL);' has a problem.  It should really have its own, local per-thread ts since it writes it upon signals, but that's just a niggle in this case.  More importantly, a requst for a 10ns sleep is an unreasonable request, and, even if a well-rounded-up delay is generated, it's likely swamped by the effects of its own overhead and that of the printf() calls, the stdout() lock of which is likely to serialize the actions of the threads anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS;i++){
        thread_id = i+1;
    if(pthread_create(&thread_id,&attributes,add10,thread_id) != 0)
```

You are using the same variable `thread_id` for all threads.You need an array here.

```
pthread_t thread_id[10];
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS;i++){
    if(pthread_create(&thread_id[i],&attributes,add10,thread_id[i]) != 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This indeed fixed the error!

Answer (score 1):

Well, essentially you are waiting for only one thread to join and ignored remaining 9 threads

```
   for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++){
            pthread_join (thread_id,NULL);
    }
```

because of this create statement

```
 if(pthread_create(&thread_id,&attributes,add10,thread_id) != 0)
```